Find the difference in days inside a Pivot table
I'm trying to find the difference in days within a Pivot table or just within the table itself. I have the following situation (I'll add the table to copy on the bottom of my question)
I have several columns and I want to calculate the difference in time(days) within the same AAA group with values in the DDD column (red numbers in example below). And if possible, also the difference in time(days) within the same AAA group and the same BBB group with values in the DDD column (green numbers in example below).
This is the data table:

(I don't have enough rep. points to insert the image)
And this is the Pivot table, with next to it the values I want to find automated. The red values are the most important for me, but the green values would also be helpfull.
 (links to picture)
(I don't have enough rep. points to insert the image)
Summary of what I want:
The time in days between the first day and last day in every layer of the pivot table. So in the pivot example, the days in red, green and blue. Item 44 (column AAA) gives the best example of the values.
The table to copy:



AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD




11
0
A
10-1-2020


11
0
B
11-2-2020


11
0
C
14-3-2020


11
0
D
15-4-2020


22
0
A
15-3-2024


22
0
B
20-3-2024


22
0
B
23-3-2024


22
0
C
24-3-2024


22
0
D
24-3-2024


33
0
A
2-3-2022


33
0
B
3-3-2022


33
0
C
4-3-2022


33
0
D
5-3-2022


33
1
A
6-3-2022


33
1
B
7-3-2022


33
1
B
8-3-2022


33
1
B
9-3-2022


33
1
B
10-3-2022


33
1
C
11-3-2022


33
1
C
12-3-2022


33
1
C
13-3-2022


33
1
D
14-3-2022


44
0
A
6-8-2022


44
0
A
3-11-2022


44
0
A
31-1-2023


44
0
A
30-4-2023


44
0
B
28-7-2023


44
0
B
25-10-2023


44
0
B
22-1-2024


44
0
C
20-4-2024


44
0
D
18-7-2024


44
0
D
15-10-2024


44
1
A
12-1-2025


44
1
B
11-4-2025


44
1
C
9-7-2025


44
1
D
6-10-2025


44
2
A
3-1-2026


44
2
B
2-4-2026


44
2
C
30-6-2026


44
2
D
27-9-2026




Do you mind using Excel formulas?
If not, you may check my workaround:
Firstly, using "Group By" function in Excel to get the groups. I have shown the steps in your another thread:
Excel, how to find which groups in one column have different values in another column
You will get the table like following:

Then you may use Maxifs and Minifs functions.

Differences for CCC:

=MAXIFS(Table2[DDD],Table2[AAA],G2,Table2[BBB],H2,Table2[CCC],I2)-MINIFS(Table2[DDD],Table2[AAA],G2,Table2[BBB],H2,Table2[CCC],I2)

Differences for BBB:

=MAXIFS(Table2[DDD],Table2[AAA],G2,Table2[BBB],H2)-MINIFS(Table2[DDD],Table2[AAA],G2,Table2[BBB],H2)

Differences for AAA:

=MAXIFS(Table2[DDD],Table2[AAA],G2)-MINIFS(Table2[DDD],Table2[AAA],G2)

